# How to use React with Typescript and SASS

Tags: reactjs, sass

I am bootstrapping my app using the [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) and I want to develop using Typescript and SASS. I have been using Angular before where I could easily reference the SASS file like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'unit-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  providers: []
})
```

In React I am trying to import the SASS file like this:

```
import s from "./mystyles.scss";
```

But I am getting the error

> Cannot find module "./mystyles.scss"

.
How can I import the SASS file into the .tsx file?

Comment: Checkout [create-react-app with Sass](https://www.robinwieruch.de/create-react-app-with-sass-support/)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Assuming you have successfully installed `node-sass` in a TypeScript `create-react-app` React application, just as you would [Add/import a CSS stylesheet](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-stylesheet) by doing the following:

```
import './mystyles.css';
```

For a SCSS stylesheet, you would simply change the file type:

```
import './mystyles.scss';
```

In your example you simple need to treat it as a [Import a module for its side effects only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Import_a_module_for_its_side_effects_only) instead of a default import like you are currently attempting.

You can also treat it as a [SCSS Module](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet#docsNav) by updating the SCSS filename to `mystyles.module.scss` and importing it as follows:

```
import styles as './mystyles.module.scss';
```

I was able to achieve both bits of functionality doing the following as Sass/SCSS support is built in by default in `react-scripts@2.0.0` and higher projects:

1. Created a TypeScript create-react-app using command `npx
   create-react-app my-app --template typescript`
2. Navigated into the create
   directory and install node-sass using command `npm install --save
   node-sass`
3. Changed default generated `App.css` to `App.scss`
4. Changed import in `App.tsx` from `import './App.css';` to `import './App.scss';`

Make sure you have `node-sass` installed. If that doesn't help, you may need to revisit how you created/converted your `create-react-app` to be in TypeScript.

You need to either import it as `import './mystyles.scss';` or actually put `module` in the file name and import it as `import whatever from './mystyles.module.scss';`.

Comment: hi can you put scss styles in variable in a TSX file ?

Comment: I tried and not working for me,scss file works like simple css when i import scss files as modules in components(in my react-ts-starter).I dont know how things stands with "create-react-app" . @Barcode HJ

Comment: Just for record, `@import` will be deprecated in favor of `@use` and `@forward`, and support [will be dropped](https://github.com/sass/sass/blob/main/accepted/module-system.md#timeline) by 2022 at the latest.

Comment: Including Node Sass, are deprecated. If you're a user of Node Sass, you can migrate to Dart Sass by replacing node-sass in your package.json file with sass